# higher reciprocity theorems from ratios of Gauss sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

One recent proof of quadratic reciprocity involves computing various rations of the Gauss sum.

---

In [**Quadratic reciprocity and the sign of the Gauss sum via the finite Weil representation**](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2447) Gurevich, Hadani and Howe discuss the [Gauss sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum), which are finite field analogues of the Gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)$:

$$ G_p = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p} e^{\frac{2\pi i x^2}{p}} = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{rc} \sqrt{p} & \text{if }p \equiv 1 \mod 4 \\ 
i\sqrt{p} & \text{if }p \equiv 3 \mod 4\end{array}\right.$$

with the relationship $G_p^2 = (\tfrac{-1}{p})\cdot p$.  Using properties of the [Weil representation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0202) of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, and the fact that the Finite Fourier Transform corresponds to

$$ S = \left( \begin{array}{cr} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

they are able to prove quadratic reciprocity and correctly get the sign of the Legendre symbol.  In fact, they compute the ratio:

$$  (\tfrac{p}{q}) (\tfrac{q}{p}) = \frac{G_p \cdot G_q}{G_{pq}}$$

---

The expression on the right looks like a [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) for the divisors of $pq$.   So I started trying other combinations to see if I got meaningful symbols. Using three variables:

$$ \frac{G_p G_q G_r G_{pqr}}{G_{pq}G_{qr}G_{pr}} \equiv 1$$

Computer experiments showed this ratio always to be $1$.  In order to fine more interesting behavior I found:

$$ \frac{G_p G_q G_r }{G_{pqr}} \equiv \pm 1$$

And there is no reason to stop there since Mobius functions can be defined for any [lattice](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~levine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-12.pdf) using [incidence algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra).  In particular, the poset of numbers and their divisors.

Is there a name for these generalized symbols, or are these trivial extensions of the original Legendre symbol?  Finally, what is the rule determining the sign in the second example?

Comment: Maybe you should mention that generally, the summation for $G_n$ is just over $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb F_p$ for primes. :)

Comment: Has the sign of $\frac{G_p G_q G_r }{G_{pqr}}$ no correlation with the sign of, say, $i^{pqr}$ or with $\frac{i^{pqr}}{i^{p+q+r}}$?

Comment: @Wolfgang The formula for Gauss sum holds for odd primes.  And the factor of 1 or $i$ has to be carefully checked. $G_{pqr} \propto \sqrt{pqr}$ but we dont know which square root of $-1$ to put there.

Comment: I know. But I mean you are talking about $G_{pq}$ without defining it. And when I mentioned the sign of $i^{pqr}$, that was just a synonyme for some conjectural link with $p,q,r\mod 4$. (4 cases)

Comment: @Wolfgang it's something like $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}(-1)^{\frac{r-1}{2}}$ but it could be some other joint parity condition mod 4. For example it must be symmetric upon interchanging $p, q, r$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at bit further in the preprint you will see that the authors also state the generalisation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{G_{n_1} G_{n_2}}{G_{n_1 n_2}} = \left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}\right) \left(\frac{n_2}{n_1}\right)
\end{equation*}
for any coprime odd numbers $n_1$, $n_2$. From this it easy to see that indeed
\begin{equation*}
\frac{G_p G_q G_r G_{pqr}}{G_{pq} G_{qr} G_{pr}}=1,
\end{equation*}
and that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{G_p G_q G_r}{G_{pqr}}=
\begin{cases}
+1 & \mbox{if at most one of $p$, $q$ and $r$ is $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$,}\\
-1 & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
In general the formula also shows that such "balanced" quotients as above always can be converted to a symmetric product of Legendre symbols which in turn only depends on the congruence classes mod $4$ for the primes involved.